# Joomla3 installation on local (XAMPP) stuck on step 2

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost, joomla3.3

I'm trying to setup Joomla 3 on my localhost on XAMPP. I have extracted the Joomla files in htdocs/myFolder.
Once i launch the site, it takes me to Joomla site configuration.

Step1. Main Configuration-
I provide site name, description, admin email, username blah blah.

Step2. Database configuration-
I provide the following information:

`Database Type: MySQLi
Hostname: localhost:81 (because my apache runs on port 81)
username: joomla_admin (user i have created in phpmyadmin)
password: "password for above user"
database name: "dbname which i created already"
table prefic: "random generated"
Old db process: Remove`

Once i click Next, the loading bar shows up and keeps loading to the end of the world.

Please help!

Comment: You probably need to increase the max_execution_time PHP parameter. So edit php.ini file used by Apache, and change `max_execution_time = 600` for example. Put it back to whatever it was originally, when you are finished with the install.

Comment: No help.. Running as admin.

Comment: I tried installing Joomla3 via XAMPP's initial webpage. It worked.